# ngFor doesn't display correct data Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, ngfor, angular12

I have a variable `forms` where I save some forms that will be displayed inside a for loop.

```
forms: UserForm[] = [
        {   
            id: 1
            name: 'experience',
            show: true
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'work',
            show: true
        },
        ....
    ]
```

Here when I load the data on the template I filter `forms` based on the `show` :

```
<div *ngFor="let tab of (filterForms | generalPipe:forms)" class="form-container">
 // some code 
</div>
```

And this is the filter function

```
    filterForms(tabs: UserForm[]): UserForm[] {
        return forms.filter((item) => item.show);
    }
```

I have another function that changes the show for a specific form inside form with id `experience`

```
   hideExperienceForm(){ 
      forms[0].show = false;
   }
```

The problem is that on Html the form is still being displayed even though I call the `hideExperienceForm()` and the `show` is set to `false` for the first item. Also if I show on the HTML template the  `show` is false too but the loop is not getting the update and it doesn't call `filterForms` again. How can I trigger `filterForms` inside `*ngFor` to be triggered?

Comment: why are you using the filterForms function instead of looping the forms by using *ngFor and rendering the HTML if the show is true.

Comment: because on load all are true, but then when selecting some other options some of the forms should be hidden. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: @cfprabhu could you please elaborate?

Comment: @onwkbapzjamrhoescc and on `forms` changes angular will re-run ngFor directive and update list. Whereas submitting main data as pipe parameter looks really awkward.

Answer (score 3):

What if you use *ngIf instead of the filter?

```
<div *ngFor="let form of forms" class="form-container">
    <div *ngIf="form.show">
        // Some code
    </div>
</div>
```

If a form is changed to show = false it should become hidden.